# PostgresException: 42883: function X(timestamp without time zone) does not exist when trying to call procedure

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, asp.net-core

I am trying to call stored procedure using .net core.

I had [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462479/syntax-error-at-end-of-input-while-trying-to-launch-stored-procedure-from-db) problem. After fixing my previous problem, I have another syntax error.

> PostgresException: 42883: function GetActiveUserPackagesForOpenBillingPeriod(timestamp without time zone) does not exist when trying to call procedure

This is the code:

```
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        List<ActivePackageForOpenBillingPeriod> activeUserPackagesForOpenBillingPeriod = null;

        using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection ("Host=localhost;Port=xxx;Database=postgres;Username=postgres;Password=xxx;TrustServerCertificate=true;ApplicationName=xxx;")) 
        {                
            var s = "Select * FROM \"GetActiveUserPackagesForOpenBillingPeriod\"({0})";
            activeUserPackagesForOpenBillingPeriod = context.ActivePackageForOpenBillingPeriods.FromSql (s, date).ToList ();

        }
```

Stored Procedure

```
create or replace function "GetActiveUserPackagesForOpenBillingPeriod"(somedate timestamp without time zone) returns TABLE("Amount" numeric, "Package" integer, "User" integer, "Account" integer, "AcceptanceActID" integer, "HasChangedPackage" boolean)
language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE
    BEGIN
      RETURN QUERY
        SELECT
            up."TotalAmount",
            up."PackageID",
            u."ID" AS "UserId",
            a."ID" AS "AccountId",
            th."AcceptanceActID",


            CASE
                  WHEN count(DISTINCT tl."PackageID") IN (0,1)  THEN false
                  ELSE true
            END AS "HasChangedPackage"

        FROM public."Accounts" as a
            LEFT JOIN billing."TransactionHeaders" AS th ON th."AccountID" = a."ID"
            INNER JOIN security."Users" AS u ON u."AccountID"= a."ID"
            INNER JOIN billing."UserPackages" AS up ON up."UserID"=u."ID" AND COALESCE(th."Date", date) BETWEEN up."StartDate" AND COALESCE(up."EndDate", date)
            LEFT JOIN billing."TransactionLines" AS tl ON th."Id" = tl."TransactionHeaderID"

        WHERE th."AcceptanceActID" IS NULL AND a."StatusID"!=4 AND a."StatusID"!=3 AND up."StatusID"=1


        GROUP BY a."ID", u."ID", up."PackageID", 
up."TotalAmount",th."AcceptanceActID";
RETURN;

END;
$$;

alter function "GetActiveUserPackagesForOpenBillingPeriod"(timestamp)  
owner 
to postgres;
```

Class

```
public class ActivePackageForOpenBillingPeriod {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey ("AccountID")]
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey ("UserID")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int PackageID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey ("PackageID")]
    public Package Package { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public bool HasChangedPackage { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Maybe a `search_path` problem.

Comment: try call the function direct on postgre first

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I ran this 
Select * FROM GetActiveUserPackagesForOpenBillingPeriod(to_date('20190101','YYYYDDMM'))
and error says "function getactiveuserpackagesforopenbillingperiod(date) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 15"

Comment: isnt date is a keyword in postgress?

Comment: @cdev yes. I changed parameter to 'somedate'. Still the same output. I changed parameters in query. Turns out they were not in order. So, I got a desirable output after running select query IN db. However, still facing the same problem

Comment: try without parameter first. just call and see weather you are getting results in .net

Comment: @cdev it says "function GetActiveUserPackagesForOpenBillingPeriod() does not exist"

Comment: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html see stored procedure section

Comment: @cdev That case(from the link) would not be useful for me. I am trying to put values in List<ActivePackageForOpenBillingPeriod> activeUserPackagesForOpenBillingPeriod variable.

Comment: Do you get that message running the query direct in postgres? Then check if you create the function in a different schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the

**> @DateFrom::DATE**

The code is given below. I using the **Dapper** to call the function.

```
Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
            var f = _connection.Query<GeneralLedgerForSubsidyAccount>(@"
                                                       SELECT * FROM 
                                                       edudb.Fn_General_Ledger_Subsidy_Account
                                                       (@SearchType, @DateFrom::DATE, @DateTo::DATE, @OpeningBalanceIncludeORExcluding, @ChartOfAccountsId)
                                                     ",
                                                     new
                                                     {
                                                         SearchType = search.SearchType,
                                                         DateFrom = search.DateFrom.Date,
                                                         DateTo = search.DateTo.Date,
                                                         OpeningBalanceIncludeORExcluding = search.OpeningBalanceIncludeORExcluding,
                                                         ChartOfAccountsId = search.ChartOfAccountsId
                                                     }).ToList();
```

My function definition like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION edudb.Fn_General_Ledger_Subsidy_Account
(
    Search_Type character varying(50),
    date_from DATE,
    date_to DATE,
    Opening_Balance_Include_Or_Exclude  character varying(50),
    chart_of_accounts_id_p INTEGER
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use timestamp parameter, you must use the varchar parameter. 
And in the stored procedure you change the type varchar for the timestamp.

Comment: You created function "GetActiveUserPackagesForOpenBillingPeriod" but in a later post indicated you called function getactiveuserpackagesforopenbillingperiod. Those are NOT the same. When you define put an object with name in double quotes  (") the name becomes case sensitive so you must use the quotes and case be exactly the same. Solution, don't use the quotes.